# How to find out the coordinates of points on the main diagonal (not exactly approximately)?

Tags: math, matrix

There is such an image.
How to automatically draw a diagonal where there are most white dots?
Any ideas?
The resulting line should be continuous and one pixel thick,
[image]

Comment: See [Linear Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). For a simple straight it's very easy. For a polygon you need several passes. For a polynomial solution use LR too, but with more maths.

Comment: I don't think linear regression works here. The deviation from the main diagonal is not known in advance, moreover, there may be gaps in the original data, as in the image. Or am I wrong? Is there some kind of python?

Comment: Your image shows a polygon. It may have been calculated using several, very short in X-dimension, LR ranges

Comment: yes, you are probably right, polynomial regression does a pretty good job, but there is a problem. These are the ends of the range. At the edges, a deviation from the diagonal is obtained. How to deal with it?

Comment: You can't, that's a definition characteristic of a polynomial fit. Why is linear regression not good enough if what you're showing looks like several linear fits? But of course the real question is: _what are you showing here_? What is this data and why is linear regression not good enough?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def main():
    synchronize, L_word, R_word, L_end, R_end = get_sim_v2()
    synchronize = find_max_path_v2(synchronize)
    img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(synchronize * 255), 'L')
    img.save(f"input.png")

    image = filtered_main_diag("input.png")
    synchronize = np.asarray(np.uint8(image * 100))
    image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image * 255))
    image.save("output1.png")

    two_sync = create_sync_v2(synchronize, L_word, R_word, L_end, R_end,
                              len(L_word) - 1, len(R_word) - 1)
    for i in range(len(synchronize)):
        for j in range(len(synchronize[i])):
            synchronize[i][j] = 0
    for i in two_sync:
        synchronize[i[L_a]][i[L_b]] = 255
    img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(synchronize), 'L')
    img.save("output2.png")
```

Full source example https://github.com/xayam/examples/tree/main/sync_main_diagonal

[image: Input image]

[image: Output image]

polynomial regression doesn't work well with such inputs